# Conditional Expectation of future return

Tags: time-series, conditional-expectation

Suppose the expected return in $t+1$, conditional on all information available at time $t$ is given by

$$ E_{t}[r_{t+1}] = r + x_t, $$ where r is a constant and $x_t$ is observable at time $t$. $x_t$ follows an AR(1) process,
$$ x_t = \phi x_{t-1} + \xi_t, \qquad \xi_t \sim (0,\sigma).$$

Is there an easy way to get to 
$$ E_t[r_{t+T+1}]?$$

Comment: Are you sure that's what you want to ask?  It would seem more useful to ask for the *conditional* expectation given all values through time $t$.

Comment: stollenm, since the required conditioning is on information as of time $t$, not $t+T$, Cagdas' first sentence is redundant. But he got you the answer by his last sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like the subscript notation under the expectation. It gave me the impression that left side is a constant but right side is random.

Using the given formula

$E[r_{t+T+1} | x_{t + T}] = r + x_{t+T}$

Now using law of iterated expectations

$E[E[r_{t+T+1} | x_{t + T}] | x_t] = E[r_{t+T+1} | x_t] = r + E[x_{t+T} | x_t]$

Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation section "Iterated expectations with nested conditioning sets" for this step.

From autoregression we know that

$E[x_{t+1}] = \phi E[x_{t}] + E[\xi_{t+1}]$

$E[\xi_{t+1}]$ is given to be 0. In that case if we are given $x_t$ then $E[x_{t+T} | x_t] = \phi^T x_t$ by induction.

Hence

$E[r_{t+T+1} | x_t] = r + \phi^T x_t$

Comment: @Cadgas, I don't get the equality $E[E[r_{t+T+1}]|x_t] = E[r_{t+T+1}|x_t]$. Is this generally true or only in this case?